# Security settings in IE that cause not loading all page components

Tags: ajax, security

The situation is this: site was added as trusted in IE, I'm able to open it, but not all components in a webpage are visible. The page contains multiple tabs (that use AJAX), with a tab as default. When trying to access other tabs, they appear empty (tab content doesn't load). So, always only the default tab opens with loaded content, the others don't.
What security settings in IE can cause this?

Comment: Do those AJAX tabs loading data from same domain?

Comment: Yes, from same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable "active scripting" and allow the browser to run safe ActiveX modules in older versions of IE. The usual work-around involves using an iframe for IE since most people will not add the domain to the trusted domain list and deal with all of IE's warnings about security being lowered (or they don't have access to those settings in their workstations because of a group policy set by IT).

After IE 6 they started using the standards approach... check out [this reference from Microsoft on the XMLHTTP object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Also you have to actually be able to call the other windows by name in your instance (since there is no main DOM-accessible listing of available windows and tabs), which means that you would need to have opened them from the initial window so you can setup the Javascript reference as a reusable variable.

```
var Window1 = window.open();
```